# how to have an event when there is a change in list (collection editor)

Tags: c#

this is the very first time i ask question at here. If i didn't follow the rules please let me know and please let me know if you unable to understand my english, i will try my best to let you know my problem.

```
public List<TeachPosUC> tp = new List<TeachPosUC>();
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<TeachPosUC> _TeachPos
{
    get { return tp;}
}
```

Basically the  is a customer user control. What i want to do is just add all item in the tp to a table layout. My code like below:

```
tblLayout.Controls.Add(new TeachPosUC());
```

the main problem i faced is, how to detect we clicked the collection editor's "OK" button. By knowing the "OK" button was clicked, i can add the new User Control to the table layout.

Can anybody give me a hand on this, or is there any better way? I search through online, but can't get what I want. May be i searched the wrong keyword, if this question is duplicated, please kindly provide me a link direct to the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Button will have a click event . Wire up the event to a event handler

Comment: List<T> derives from object and doesn't have an event model. Either grab the click etc or wrap it in a class with setter properties!

Comment: MVC, asp.net or winforms?

Comment: Please post the relevant code related to the UI (XAML, code behind classes, etc).

Comment: Have a read of this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: use ObservableCollection<T> instead of List<T>. It has notification property for changes made on list. Otherwise u need to create custom list.